# libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll was not found

Tags: c++, boost, codeblocks

I have build the boost binary and linked them into code::blocks project.
When I run the program it says it cant find `libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll`
So what am I doing wrong and how to solve this?

code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;


    if ( !boost::filesystem::exists( "myfile.txt" ) )
    {
      cout << "Can't find my file!" <<endl;
    }
}
```

[image: Error]
[image: Linker Settings]

Comment: Is that file in the same folder as your .exe file for your application? If not did you alter your `PATH` environment variable such that the folder containing this dll is one of the paths.

Comment: which file? " myfile.txt? " or the .dll one? none of them in same folder btw

Comment: `libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll` must be in a location where your OS will look. Probably other boost dlls will also be in that folder.

Comment: yes, there are other dlls also, where should i put the 'libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll'?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order

Comment: i just put these dlls in C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin.The PATH Env Var was set here. This time this program works perfectly. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You don't move the .dll files. What is needed is to enter the name of the needed .a file into Linker settings/Link libraries in Project Options.